# Is there a way to have one event hanlder for these 3 events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

How can I consolidate these 3 event handlers into 1?  There is only one property in my action which is different.

```
  clickHandler1 () {
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'updateMenuFave', current: '1' });
  }
  clickHandler2 () {
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'updateMenuFave', current: '280' });
  }
  clickHandler3 () {
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'updateMenuFave', current: '268' });
  }
```

**Relevant React/JSX**

```
  <div id = 'arc_hold'>
    <img className='arcs' id="arc_arc" src="../_images/arc_arc.svg" onClick={this.clickHandler1.bind(this)} ></img>
    <img className='arcs' id="arc_news" src="../_images/arc_news.svg" onClick={this.clickHandler2.bind(this)} ></img>
    <img className='arcs' id="arc_sw" src="../_images/arc_sw.svg" onClick={this.clickHandler3.bind(this)} ></img>
  </div>
```

Comment: so pass in arguments....

Comment: What is the parameter list for a click handler in React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reuse the handler:

```
  clickHandler(current) {
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'updateMenuFave', current: current });
  }
```

And bind the argument:

```
  <div id = 'arc_hold'>
    <img className='arcs' id="arc_arc" src="../_images/arc_arc.svg" onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this, '1')} ></img>
    <img className='arcs' id="arc_news" src="../_images/arc_news.svg" onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this, '280')} ></img>
    <img className='arcs' id="arc_sw" src="../_images/arc_sw.svg" onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this, '268')} ></img>
  </div>
```

You can read more about bind [at the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: worked, I just had to add a `toString()` to current.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the use cases of storing the values as `data-*` attributes.

```
<img className='arcs' id="arc_arc" src="../_images/arc_arc.svg" data-value="1" onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)} ></img>
<img className='arcs' id="arc_news" src="../_images/arc_news.svg" data-value="280" onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)} ></img>
<img className='arcs' id="arc_sw" src="../_images/arc_sw.svg" data-value="268" onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)} ></img>

clickHandler (e) {
    this.props.dispatch({type: 'updateMenuFave', current: e.target.getAttribute('data-value') });
  }
```

Comment: never, ever store data in the DOM with react. that's the point of using react!!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to extract these into sub-components. It's a little more verbose, but it makes things cleaner, and will prevent unnecessary re-renders.

```
class ArcImg extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onImageClick(this.props.current);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      onImageClick,
      ...otherProps
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <img
        className="arcs"
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        {...otherProps}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

---

```
// you should bind this.clickHandler in the constructor or use property initializer
<div id="arc_hold">
  <ArcImg
    id="arc_arc"
    src="../_images/arc_arc.svg"
    onImageClick={this.clickHandler}
  />
  <ArcImg
    id="arc_news"
    src="../_images/arc_news.svg"
    onImageClick={this.clickHandler}
  />
  <ArcImg
    id="arc_sw"
    src="../_images/arc_sw.svg"
    onImageClick={this.clickHandler}
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reusing handler:

```
  clickHandler(current) {
   this.props.dispatch({type: 'updateMenuFave', current: current });
  }
```

JSX:

```
  <div id = 'arc_hold'>
   <img className='arcs' id="arc_arc" src="../_images/arc_arc.svg" 
    onClick={() => this.clickHandler('1')} ></img>
   <img className='arcs' id="arc_news" src="../_images/arc_news.svg" 
    onClick={() => this.clickHandler('280')} ></img>
   <img className='arcs' id="arc_sw" src="../_images/arc_sw.svg" 
    onClick={() => this.clickHandler('268')} ></img>
  </div>
```